# Angular 2 http call

Tags: angular

I'm a bit confused on how to do a http get call. My **app.service** is like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
constructor(private http: Http){}
    fetchData(){
    return this.http.get('http://date.jsontest.com/').map(
        (res) = > res.json()
        ).subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data)
    );
    }
}
```

This leads to an error of `Cannot find name 'res'`.

My **app.module** has the HttpModule.

Having looked through the [Angular 2 doc on HTTP requests](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html), they have something like `getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]>`. But I am not sure exactly what is contained under the `import { Hero } from './hero';` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`(res) = > res.json()`

that should be

`(res) => res.json`

Comment: Wow. I am hopeless. Still, after fixing that, I get another error. This time it says `this.http.get(...).map is not a function`

Comment: Got it. I then had to import `import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: I was just about to say you can just import only the map operator from rxjs
instead of the whole rxjs library